# Conditional property type

Tags: json, jsonschema

How can I create a JSON Schema which has a conditional property type based on the value of another property.

I have this:

```
    { // Header info removed for brevity
      "definitions": {
        "payloadTypeA": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "requestType": {"type": "string","enum": ["A1", "A2"]}},
        },
        "payloadTypeB": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "requestType": {"type": "string","enum": ["B1","B2"]}}
        }
      },
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "workload": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": ["A","B"]
        },
        "payload": {
          "oneOf": [
            {
              "if": {"properties": {"workload": {"const": "A"}}},
              "then": {"$ref": "#/definitions/payloadTypeA"}},
            {
              "if": {"properties": {"workload": {"const": "B"}}},
              "then": {"$ref": "#/definitions/payloadTypeB"}}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

I would expect this to use PayloadTypeA when the value of `workload` is "A" and PayloadTypeB when `workload` is "B".  However, this validates:

```
{
  "workload": "B",
  "payload": {
    "requestType": "A1",
  }
}
```

This also validates:

```
{
  "workload": "B",
  "payload": {
    "requestType": "B1",
  }
}
```

But this does not:

```
{
  "workload": "B",
  "payload": {
    "requestType": "C1",
  }
}
```

So it seems that it is validating against either payload schema, regardless of the value of workload.

I have other conditions for workload values, so I can't use just a plain `if/then/else` as I'd have a large nested structure of `if/then/else` which would be a nightmare to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of issues. Let's start with a simplified version of part of your schema.

```
"properties": {
  "workload": { "enum": ["A","B"] },
  "payload": {
    "if": { "properties": { "workload": { "const": "A" } } },
    "then": { "$ref": "#/definitions/payloadTypeA" }
  }
}
```

When you put the `if` schema here, the "workload" property is expected under the "payload" property, not at the top level. This would work if you were validating a structure that looked like this.

```
{
  "payload": {
    "workload": "B",
    "requestType": "B1",
  }
}
```

To get this to work, you have to pull the `if`/`then` block up to a higher level of the schema where it has access to the "workload" property.

```
"properties": {
  "workload": { "enum": ["A","B"] }
},
"if": { "properties": { "workload": { "const": "A" } } },
"then": { "properties": { "payload": { "$ref": "#/definitions/payloadTypeA" } } }
```

The next issue is how to combine conditionals. Combining the above fix with what you have now, it would look something like this.

```
"properties": {
  "workload": { "enum": ["A","B"] }
},
"oneOf": [
  {
    "if": { "properties": { "workload": { "const": "A" } } },
    "then": { "properties": { "payload": { "$ref": "#/definitions/payloadTypeA" } } }
  },
  {
    "if": { "properties": { "workload": { "const": "B" } } },
    "then": { "properties": { "payload": { "$ref": "#/definitions/payloadTypeB" } } }
  }
]
```

When an `if` fails, it doesn't fail the schema. The schema will only fail if `if` passes *and* `then` is false. So, if given a valid schema like this.

```
{
  "workload": "B",
  "payload": {
    "requestType": "B1",
  }
}
```

- `/oneOf/0` will pass because `/oneOf/0/if` fails.
- `/oneOf/1` will pass because `/oneOf/1/if` passes and `/oneOf/1/then` passes.

Since both schemas pass, the `oneOf` fails. You can extrapolate from this example, that the schema should pass only when all of the conditionals pass. Just replace `oneOf` with `allOf` and it should work.

```
"properties": {
  "workload": { "enum": ["A","B"] }
},
"allOf": [
  {
    "if": { "properties": { "workload": { "const": "A" } } },
    "then": { "properties": { "payload": { "$ref": "#/definitions/payloadTypeA" } } }
  },
  {
    "if": { "properties": { "workload": { "const": "B" } } },
    "then": { "properties": { "payload": { "$ref": "#/definitions/payloadTypeB" } } }
  }
]
```